# I am working on a project, and I've been trying to come up with a custom loss/score function. Would really appreciate some help

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, statistics, loss-function

So, the loss function needs to be a function of (say) two variables A and B. It needs to be continous and differentiable in terms of A. Basically, I have a set of precomputed values (B), and during training, after every forward pass, I get a value A. A can vary from 0 to 1. And B can vary from 0 to (say) a bit large value, 10.

Now, this is how I want the loss function to work :

A - high, B - high
=> Ideal situation. Loss should be a small value i.e. No change in A required.

A - high, B - low
=> Loss should be such that it moves towards decreasing the value of A.

A - low, B - high
=> Loss should be such that it moves towards increasing the value of A.

A - low, B - low
=> Ideal situation. Loss should be a small value i.e. No change in A required.

Comment: A few things are not clear. What do you mean by A being "high" or "low"? Same for B? What should happen when A is neither high nor low? What should happen when B is neither high nor low? Are you actually wanting A to be close as possible to 0.1 B? If not, please give some *numerical* examples of when you want a high loss and when you want a low loss. You should note that a loss function says nothing directly about what should change to make itself lower. You have to add that part (e.g. by implementing gradient descent), and are usually in control of what needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of computing $A$, make your algorithm compute $10\times A.$
Then use your favourite loss function for continuous variables. The most common one is the squared $L^2$-norm $l(10\times A, B) = (10\times A-B)^2.$

Here is a plot of $l$ that I made with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot(10*A-B)%5E2,%20A%20in%20(0,1),%20B%20in%20(0,10)):[image: Quadratic loss function].